# Access cookies in a react app hosted on AWS Cloudfront-S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cookies

I have a react project hosted on `AWS S3 bucket` & served through `Cloudfront`. Also, it is integrated with API Gateway to authorize the user visiting my react app. As soon as the user is authorized, it is being redirected to the dashboard, with his/her credentials info stored in the form of `cookies` into the browser.

The format of the cookies look like this:

[image]

I need to access those cookies (idToken to be specific) from the browser and sent it further as the Auth Token inside the header of the backend request.

I tried using the npm package [react-cookies](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/blob/v1.0.5/README.md), but it doesn't seems to work. It keeps throwing an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined`.

I tried the following approach:

```
import cookie  from 'react-cookie';

const getCookies = () => {
    const auth_token = cookie.get('CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.1an******************************133.idToken', {
        httpOnly: false
    });

    console.log('auth token extracted', auth_token);
}

export default getCookies;
```

I am very much new to handling cookies & auth on AWS. If any help to resolve the same, will be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understood completely, so you need a function to extract the cookie by name from document.cookie is that what you are looking, And once you get the cookie what you need to do

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS using `document.cookie` will work for the code deployed on AWS CloudFront too?

Comment: The cookie is stored in the browser of the user and the method suggested by @DILEEPTHOMAS is a native API supported by practically any browser regardless of where the code is deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the cookie, instead of using library you can write a function and pass the key name.

```
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}
```

So in your case you can get the value by calling the function and passing the key. as Andre mentioned in the comment, the cookie stores in the browser. So you can access it through **document.cookie**

For example in your case.

```
// console.log(getCookie('CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.1an******************************133.idToken'))
```

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks a lot for this. I'll definitely try this out and see the result

Comment: Sure, happy to help. If it helped you kindly vote and accept it so it will be helpful for future references for others

Comment: Just one thing though, Is it valid to directly access the `cognitoIdentityServiceProvider*******idToken` key directly into the client-side code to retrieve its value?

Comment: In the cookie the key name is already exposed isn't ??

Comment: Hi Dileep. One warning I am facing with this cookie extraction: `Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.`. But it occurs sometimes randomly. Can you help to figure this, on where should the `;` be replaced?

Comment: can you share me the sample document.cookie

Comment: Yea it looks something like this:

Comment: `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.6rhseb1dsn8kqeqmq9one86m2r.00cf5085-94ae-400f-9c7e-8d8ef69db0bf.idToken=...; CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.6rhseb1dsn8kqeqmq9one86m2r.00cf5085-94ae-400f-9c7e-8d8ef69db0bf.accessToken=...; CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.6rhseb1dsn8kqeqmq9one86m2r.00cf5085-94ae-400f-9c7e-8d8ef69db0bf.refreshToken=...; spa-auth-edge-nonce=..."`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224741/discussion-between-dileep-thomas-and-bubble-cord).

Comment: Hi. Yea code is working fine. I'm able to get the cookie value, but sometimes that warning kind of Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' also appears along with the value
Not sure if it's safe to get this warning or not if it will not cause any issue in the production